# Redefine ChoiceType and RadioType for formatting change and extra parameter addition

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

In Symfony forms there are two types involved in handling radio buttons: **ChoiceType** and **RadioType**.
**ChoiceType** is building the structure of the form by adding **RadioType** buttons as sub forms.

I wanted to add a different image beside each Radio button. To achieve this I changed the Form Theme of **choice_widget** and **radio_widget**.
It is working properly.

But now I want to be able to use radio buttons as well as my 'modified_radio_buttons'.

This is pretty difficult since RadioType is added along in the ChoiceType class by adding sub forms of 'radio' type.

```
class ChoiceType extends AbstractType
{
...
    private function addSubForms(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $choiceViews, array $options)
    {
        foreach ($choiceViews as $i => $choiceView) {
        ...
            // =============================================================
            // I would like to change this below to have 'my_radio' instead
            // =============================================================
            $choiceType = 'radio'; 
            ...
        }
        $builder->add($i, $choiceType, $choiceOpts);
```

One solution could be to create my own **MyChoiceType**, copying whole code from ChoiceType and just modifying it to add extra parameter and add 'my_radio' sub forms instead of 'radio' sub forms in the addSubForms method.

This works but it's not very clean in my opinion.

Would you have a suggestion to handle this?